# return false; or event.preventDefault(); not working. Can't find solution

Tags: jquery

Everytime I hit on the links the page reloads and send me to the top. Tried using `return false;` or `event.preventDefault();` and none worked.

I did search and found solutions to this issue. However I can't get it to work. Obviously there is something I'm missing.

Help is much appreciated. [jsFiddle code in here](http://jsfiddle.net/Eblan85/H72d4/)

Here's the code: It's an early state of a simple slideshow I'm trying to make.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#links").hide();

$(".gallery").hover(function() {

    $("#links").fadeIn(700);

}, function(){

    $("#links").fadeOut(600);  
});

$("#links a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var pic = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".gallery").hide();
    $(".gallery").fadeIn(1800);
    $(".gallery").css('background-image', 'url("' + pic + '")');


});


});

<div id="links">
    <ul id="thumb_list">
        <li>
            <a href="images/01.jpg"><img src="images/01_thumbnail.jpg" alt="0" /></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Try catching the `mousedown` event of `"#links a"` instead.

Comment: Do you see any errors in javascript console ? or perhaps you're loading those links using ajax?

Comment: Does everything else work (i.e., does the picture change)? Can you please show a sample of a link's html?

Comment: mousedown did'nt work. I'm new to jquery but I don't see any errors in the javascript console.

Yes, the image does change and the menu for the thumbnails does show and hide with hover

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8bvrT/1/ Everything seems to work fine. Check classes / ID's, external js and such.

Comment: Your HTML looks incomplete.  Is there an element with the ID of "links" that encloses your A tags?

Comment: Instead of preventDefault(), try stopPropagation()

Comment: Corrected my html and its validated now. Don't know what else to do. e.stopPropagation(); kinda messed what I'm trying to achieve, takes me to the img's url instead of changing the background of the div.

Comment: Added the whole html,css and jquery on a JsFiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/Eblan85/H72d4/ hope its helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are actually selecting the links.  Try $("#links, a) or $("a[id=links]").